# Java - Subscribe to Youtube Channel

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I was wondering, is there any way that you could add a subscriber to a YouTube Channel, programmatically in Java?

Is it simple enough that it could be like`this.addSuscriber("username", "password", "suscriberTo");`?

Would it have to use the YouTubeAPI, would it be possible with HTTP Requests through Java?

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with plain java would be pain for you. You will have to manage the whole web service authentication process, data mapping, ... by yourself.

Google offers it's own Java API for YouTube:
[YouTube Data API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3)

You will find a GitHub repository delivering you examples how to access youtube web services by using java and for your question topic also a dedicated example of managing subscriptions:
[com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.data.AddSubscription.java](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/AddSubscription.java)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try this.